# How to get cypress code coverage for iframe?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm trying to generate cypress code coverage for iframe which is part of my application.
Cypress creates an object called `__coverage__` for the instrumentation that is present in my iframe window(main content). But at the end of each spec, it shows the below message
[image]

Without an iframe, it's generating the report.

I followed this link
https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#instrument-your-application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding an `<iframe>` can affect the code coverage, since the counters in `__coverage__` are counting lines of javascript code and not HTML.

To check it out, I downloaded the latest repo from [code-coverage/tree/v3.10.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/tree/v3.10.0) and added an `<iframe>` to one of the simple examples under `/test-apps`.

The coverage report was still created even though there was now an iframe on the page.

[image]

If you can provide more details, preferably a repo I can check further - but as it stands, it seems it's not reproducible.

BTW Cypress v10 is used in the code-coverage repo (not yet visible/released on the Cypress repo).